# How can I remove extra space after `itemize` in moderncv?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, line-spacing, moderncv

In a `moderncv` document, using an `itemize` in a `cvitem` produces extra spacing after the itemized list.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\name{John}{Smith}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{List section}
\cvitem{Some category}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item the first
        \item the second
        \item the third
    \end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{Another category}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item number one
        \item number two
        \item number three
    \end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{text}{with a description}

More text.

\end{document}
```

I can add a `\vspace{-1em}` after each `itemize` to remove the space, but that seems like fighting the LaTeX rather than embracing it. Is there a setting I can change to remove the extra spacing here?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for the reminder! I forgot to come back to this question after testing, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An option to set the spacing of a `cvitem` is already provided by the `moderncv` class:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\name{John}{Smith}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{List section}
\cvitem[-1.2em]{Some category}{           %new code
    \begin{itemize}
        \item the first
        \item the second
        \item the third
    \end{itemize}
}
\cvitem[-1.2em]{Another category}{       %new code  
    \begin{itemize}
        \item number one
        \item number two
        \item number three
    \end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{text}{with a description}

More text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

See the `moderncv.cls` file:

> % makes a resume line with a header and a corresponding text
>
> % usage: \cvitem[spacing]{header}{text}

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, but still seems a bit un-LaTeX-ish, having to provide manual spacing every time (and with a fixed dimension at that): should I define a `\newcommand{cvitemnospace}[2]{\cvitem[-1.2em]{#1}{#2}}`? And where does the `1.2em` come from? Could it depend on any text attributes? Would something like `-\baselineskip` be better?

Comment: @WChargin `1.2em` was just a random number to show the option effect. As you can see in the source the default spacing is `0.25em`. I think your example of a custom macro is OK, I'd do the same if I had to apply the same custom spacing to many `cvitem`s

Answer (score 10):

Use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\name{John}{Smith}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{List section}
\cvitem{Some category}{%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item the first
        \item the second
        \item the third
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}
\cvitem{Another category}{%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item number one
        \item number two
        \item number three
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}
\cvitem{text}{with a description}

More text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also prefer to use `[t]` position specifier for the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\name{John}{Smith}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{List section}
\cvitem{Some category}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item the first
        \item the second
        \item the third
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}
\cvitem{Another category}{%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item number one
        \item number two
        \item number three
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
}
\cvitem{text}{with a description}

More text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is better - but there's really no simple option like `setitemize{nosepafter}`?

Comment: @WChargin This is the simplest option ;-) On the other hand, you may try with `enumitem` package and try to tweak  vertical dimensions. See the manual for `enumitem`.